# Modify and filter the PySpark RDD at the same time

Tags: python, performance, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark

I have an PySpark RDD in which each element is of the form `(key, val)` and it takes one of the two following forms:

```
elm1 = ((1, 2), ((3, 4), (5, 6)))  # key = (1,2), rest is val
elm2 = ((1, 2), ((3, 4), None))
```

Now, I need to do the following.

1. Detect the elements where the second part of the `val` is None (as in `elm2`) and extract them.
2. Flatten them as follows and replace `None` with tuple of empty strings:

   ```
   elm = (1, 2, 3, 4, ('', ''))
   ```

To do the above two steps in PySpark, I do:

```
elm = elm.filter(lambda x: detectNone(x))  # checks if x[-1][1] is None
elm = elm.map(formatElm) # where formatElm is a function that replaces None with tuple of empty strings and flattens the tuple.
```

In reality, the test `x[-1][1] == None` is a little complex and there is a more complex data structure being introduced in place of tuple of empty strings.

**Question:** Is there any way to speed up these operations. I think combining two operations into one may help, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think combining two operations into one may help,

It won't. But if you really insist on doing this, then `flatMap`:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([((1, 2), ((3, 4), (5, 6))), ((1, 2), ((3, 4), None))])


def detect_and_format(row):
    x, (y, z) = row
    return [x + y + (("", ""), )] if z is None else []

# [(1, 2, 3, 4, ('', ''))]
```